# Categorical distribution in JAGS

Tags: jags

How do I specify for a variable to be uniformly sampled from the discrete values $1,2,\ldots,10$ in JAGS? I guess I want to use the dcat() distribution, but I have yet to find good documentation of the parameters for this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [JAGS user manual](http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/FreeBSD/distfiles/mcmc-jags/jags_user_manual.pdf). `dcat(pi)` is defined with a density of $\pi_x/\sum_i{\pi_i}$.

Comment: So I want to pass a list of probabilities to dcat(). Can this list be specified in the JAGS model or do I have to pass it from R?

Comment: You could pass the vector `pi` from R or define it in the model file; it contains the probabilities that sum to one.

Comment: Usually the probabilities are derived from another distribution. See e.g. [mixture models](http://www.nhsilbert.net/source/2011/09/shifted-wald-mixture-models-in-winbugs/)

Comment: How would you specify a list of probabilities in JAGS directly?

Comment: I assume you want to use `dcat` as a prior. In your model specify e.g.: `mu ~ dcat(pi)`. Then specify `pi <- c(0.2,0.5,0.3)` and include it in the `jags.model` data list: `data=list(pi=pi, ...)`.

Comment: So I guess that means I cannot specify it within the .bug model-file?

Comment: `dcat(pi)` as @user12719 is correct to use, but important to note that unlike BUGS language and other specifications of categorical distributions, JAGS is not expecting `pi` to sum to 1 and normalizes it internally. This can effect the way each `pi[i]` is estimated. (answering instead of commenting as not enough rep to comment here)

Answer (score 0):

Kruschke's in his book *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis 2ed* on page 278 has following code

```
    model{
    ...
    ...
    m ~ dcat( mPriorProb[] )
    mPriorProb[1] <- .5
    mPriorProb[2] <- .5
}
```

To quote from the book:

> The argument of the dcat distribution is a vector of probabilities for
>   each category. JAGS does not allow the vector constants to be defined
>   inside the argument, like this: `m ~ dcat(c(.5,.5))`.